How to prove that for every graph G this holds: $κ′(G) = δ(G)$ if $δ(G) \ge \frac {n}{2}.$
I have a problem with proving this: for every graph $G$ this holds: $κ′(G) = δ(G)$ if $δ(G) \ge \frac {n}{2}$. I want to prove it by contradiction, so that the statement $κ′(G) \lt δ(G)$ and $δ(G) \ge \frac {n}{2}$ is not true. Let's denote $X$ as minimal edge cut (so its size is exactly $κ′(G)$ - edge connectivity of graph G), so the graph $G-X$ is composed of exactly two components, denoted as $G_1$ and $G_2$, and by Pigeonhole principle, at least one of these components has at most $\lfloor \frac {n}{2} \rfloor$ vertices, respectively WLOG component $G_1$ has at least $\lceil \frac {n}{2} \rceil$ vertices and component $G_2$ has at most $\lfloor \frac {n}{2} \rfloor$ vertices. Next denote $n_1$ as number of vertices in the component $G_1$, $n_2$ as number of vertices in the component $G_2$, $m_1$ as number of edges in the component $G_1$, and $m_2$ as number of edges in the component $G_2$.
Then for the component $G_1$ following inequalities hold: $\binom{n_1}{2} \ge m_1 = \frac {\sum_{i=1}^{n_1} deg_G(v_i) - κ′(G)}{2} \ge \frac {n_1*δ(G) - κ′(G)}{2} \ge \frac {\frac {n}{2}*δ(G) - κ′(G)}{2} \gt \frac {\frac {n}{2}*δ(G) - δ(G)}{2} = \frac {δ(G) * (\frac {n}{2} - 1)}{2} = \frac {δ(G) * (n - 2)}{4} \ge \frac {\frac {n}{2} * (n - 2)}{4} = \frac {n * (n - 2)}{8}$.
Now for the component $G_2$, following inequalities hold: $\binom{\lfloor \frac {n}{2} \rfloor }{2} \ge \binom{n_2}{2} \ge m_2 = \frac {\sum_{i=1}^{n_2} deg_G(v_i) - κ′(G)}{2} \ge \frac {n_2*δ(G) - κ′(G)}{2} \gt \frac {n_2*δ(G) - δ(G)}{2} = \frac {δ(G) * (n_2 - 1)}{2} \ge \frac {\frac {n}{2}*(n_2 - 1)}{2} \ge \frac {n_2*(n_2 - 1)}{2} = \frac {(n-n_1)*(n-n_1-1)}{2} = \frac {(-n+n_1)*(-n+n_1+1)}{2} \ge \frac {(-n+ \frac {n}{2})*(-n+\frac {n}{2}+1)}{2} = \frac {(-n+ \frac {n}{2})*(-n+\frac {n}{2}+1)}{2} = \frac {n * (n - 2)}{8}$
Okay, and now for the total number of edges in the original graph $G$, denote it as $m$, following two inequalites must hold: $δ(G) + m_1 + m_2 \gt m = κ′(G) + m_1 + m_2 \ge κ′(G) + 2*\frac {n * (n - 2)}{8} = κ′(G) + \frac {n * (n - 2)}{4}$.
But where do I need to continue, to find the contradiction with either number of vertices in graph $G$ (not equal to $n$), or some of the two assumptions: $κ′(G) \lt δ(G)$, and $δ(G) \ge \frac {n}{2}$?
Thanks for any help.

By the handshaking lemma $n_2\delta(G)\leq \sum_{v\in G_2}d_G(v) = 2|E(G_2)|+|X|$. Thus,
$$m_2\geq \frac{n_2\delta(G)-|X|}{2}.$$
Since $|X|<\delta(G)$,
$$m_2>\frac{n_2\delta(G)-\delta(G)}{2} = \frac{(n_2-1)\delta(G)}{2}. $$
But $G_2$ has at most $\binom{n_2}{2}\le \frac{n_2(n_2-1)}{2}\leq \frac{(n_2-1)\delta(G)}{2}$ edges, where the last inequallity follows from $n_2\leq\delta(G)$. So
$$
 \frac{(n_2-1)\delta(G)}{2}\geq m_2> \frac{(n_2-1)\delta(G)}{2},
$$
a contradiction.

Okay, that looks perfect, also I understand why $n_2 \le \delta(G)$, because we proposed that $n_2 \le \lfloor \frac {n}{2} \rfloor$ and also assumed from the beginning of the proof that $\frac {n}{2} \le \delta(G)$ . Really, thanks for help.

@Sam That's correct.
